# select variable from column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im really confuse, could you let me know why when I run this code i get good result:

```
agestock = agestock[(agestock['Region'] == "Europe") & (agestock['Purchased Bike'] == "Yes")]
```

**Output**

```
agestock
Region  Age Purchased Bike
4   Europe  36  Yes
7   Europe  43  Yes
9   Europe  48  Yes
```

But, when i was trying run only for one variable im  getting

```
region = df[['Region', 'Purchased Bike']]
region = region['Purchased Bike'] == "Yes"
region
```

**Output**

```
0      False
1      False
2      False
3       True
4       True
```

I need get all Region where PurchasedBike is "Yes"

Comment: `agestock`, `region`, and `df` are different dataframes, maybe that's why the results aren't the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you filtered dataframe with all the columns where Region is `Europe` and `Purchased Bike` is Yes

```
agestock = pd.DataFrame({
  'Region': {0: 'Europe', 1: 'Europe', 2: 'Europe', 3: 'APAC', 4: 'US'},  
  'Age': {0: 36, 1: 43, 2: 48, 3: 33, 4: 43},  
  'Purchased Bike': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'Yes', 2: 'Yes', 3: 'No', 4: 'Yes'}})

In [2]: agestock
Out[2]:
   Region   Age Purchased Bike
0  Europe    36            Yes
1  Europe    43            Yes
2  Europe    48            Yes
3    APAC    33             No
4      US    43            Yes

In [3]: agestock.query('Region == "Europe" and `Purchased Bike` == "Yes"')
Out[3]:
   Region   Age Purchased Bike
0  Europe    36            Yes
1  Europe    43            Yes
2  Europe    48            Yes
```

Alternative approach

```
In [4]: filter = agestock['Purchased Bike'] == 'Yes'


In [5]: agestock[filter]
Out[5]:
   Region   Age Purchased Bike
0  Europe    36            Yes
1  Europe    43            Yes
2  Europe    48            Yes
4      US    43            Yes

In [6]: agestock[filter].Region
Out[6]:
0    Europe
1    Europe
2    Europe
4        US
Name: Region, dtype: object
```

Comment: But if i want all region with purchased bike ==Yes not Just only europe

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly you're trying to achieve but I've edited my answer guessing that's what you need..

Comment: Mai I ask for one more things ? What is better if i get result:Region Purchased Bike
3 Pacific Yes
4 Europe Yes
6 Pacific Yes
I would like to count how many results are there for individual variables, i.e. how many results are Europe, North America etc.

Comment: you can use the .count() function to count the results (or group them). 

Following from the last example, you can do `agestock[filter].Region.count()` (which will give you `4`.